# People names or people's names?

Tags: apostrophe

Which is correct:

> Of all the *people names* in all the world's countries, the most common is Muhammad.

> Of all the *people's names* in all the world's countries, the most common is Muhammad.

Comment: "People's" is better, but both sound odd. Rather "The most popular name in the world is 'Muhammad'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be "people's names", because the names belong to the people, just like the countries belong to the world in the second half of your sentence.

If you say "people names", that makes 'people' an adjective describing the names, which doesn't really read very well. I suppose it differentiates it from 'animal names' for example, but I don't think that is what you mean.